# how to properly make a counter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to make a counter in angularjs, then I'll do something else with this counter, but I need the counter to work first with a var, the problem with this is that the var is not being updated :S, this will be a more complex component so I need it to be a var that can be shown as {{Var}}.

this is how I call the directive on the html

```
<div test-directive var="5">-</div>
```

this is the js directive, I tried with link and controller

```
    app.directive('testDirective',function(){
  return{
    template: '<div> -> {{myLocalVar}} <- </div>',
    scope:{
      specialVar: '=var'
    },
    link: function($scope,element,attributes){
      //console.log($scope.specialVar);
      $scope.myLocalVar = $scope.specialVar;
      //$scope.myLocalVar +=1 ;
      function doThis(){
        $scope.myLocalVar +=1 ;
        //$scope.$digest();
        console.log('in');
        if($scope.myLocalVar < 10){
          setTimeout(function(){doThis();}, 1000);
        }
      }
      doThis();
      //console.log($scope.myLocalVar);
    }
  };
});
```

Thanks by the help

Comment: here is a suggestion: http://code-maven.com/simple-in-memory-counter-with-angularjs

Comment: @KobiCohen Is the link broken? I couldn't access it.

Comment: try again. it is working for me

Comment: Perhaps it's an error in my system but I still can't access it.

Comment: @PratikBhattacharya I can acces the llink, but I think I need something a little different, gonna try with that example

Comment: @KobiCohen I created a new file just with this and it isnt, It increases to 8 because its harcoded, but it doesnt get increased to 10 with the timeout function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap changes in $apply method callback:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.myLocalVar +=1;
  });
```